# How to use Google Play Developer API to change in-app update priority

Tags: android, api, google-play-console, in-app-update

I am trying to implement in-app update feature in my app and I want to set the in-app update priority for each release so I can select type of update to use, but problem is I do not know how and where to set app update priority.

I have read all the Google docs and came to know that I have to use Google play developer APi to control the App update flow but im unable to implement.

Has anyone implemented this before? Can you please provide some code snippet?

Comment: Did you find any solution?